# Can I grant access to an entire chef_vault or only individual vault items

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-vault

I'm learning chef_vault.

I can go into my vaults and grant admins and clients (nodes) access to vault items inside the vaults, but is there a way I can grant admins and clients access to an entire vault and all its contents?

Is there an mechanism to easily add and remove access to an entire vault and also view that access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically. Every vault item is encrypted separately. You could certainly make some scripts that call `knife vault update` with the same access parameters for every item in a bag though.

Comment: hmm is this generally considered an anti-pattern? This is very new to me and one of the first things I thought was "how do I grant a role/group of nodes to a vault?". I expected it to be an integral feature of vaults- am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: This probably means you shouldn't be using chef-vault. Hell, common sense says you probably shouldn't be using chef-vault :)

Comment: But more specifically, items are the usual unit. You would just put multiple related items in a single item instead as multiple items in a single vault/bag.